# Tomcat 9.0.80: TLS 1.3 not working (Invalid Server SSL Protocol (32))

Tags: tomcat, openssl, tls1.3

I have been trying to configure tomcat to work with TLS 1.3 but it does not seem to be working.

Note:
The setup works fine with TLS 1.2

Connector configuration:

```
 <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />

 <!-- Left out for brevity -->

 <Connector SSLCertificateChainFile={path_to_chain_file}
       SSLCertificateFile={path_to_crt_file}
       SSLCertificateKeyFile={path_to_key_file}
       SSLEnabled="true"
       SSLPassword="changeit"
       SSLProtocol="TLSv1.3"
       SSLVerifyClient="none"
       URIEncoding="UTF-8"
       acceptCount="0"
       maxThreads="250"
       port="8443"
       protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
       scheme="https"
       secure="true"
       server="someName"
       sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.3"/>
```

Catalina.out:

```
28-Dec-2023 06:13:00.194 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent An older version [1.2.23] of the Apache Tomcat Native library is installed, while Tomcat recommends a minimum version of [1.2.38]
28-Dec-2023 06:13:00.194 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.23] using APR version [1.6.3].
28-Dec-2023 06:13:00.194 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true], UDS [false].
28-Dec-2023 06:13:00.194 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
28-Dec-2023 06:13:00.197 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1l  24 Aug 2021 SUSE release 150400.7.53.1]
28-Dec-2023 06:13:00.563 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
28-Dec-2023 06:13:00.580 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["https-openssl-nio-8443"]


28-Dec-2023 06:13:00.608 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException Failed to initialize component [Connector["https-openssl-nio-8443"]]
  org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:1011)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:554)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:1040)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:746)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:307)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:477)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error initializing SSL context
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:107)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:71)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:236)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1324)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1337)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:75)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:1009)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Error initializing SSL context
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLContext.<init>(OpenSSLContext.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLUtil.createSSLContextInternal(OpenSSLUtil.java:73)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.createSSLContext(SSLUtilBase.java:252)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:105)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Unable to create SSLContext. Check that SSLEngine is enabled in the AprLifecycleListener, the AprLifecycleListener has initialised correctly and that a valid SSLProtocol has been specified
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLContext.<init>(OpenSSLContext.java:158)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Invalid Server SSL Protocol (32)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jni.SSLContext.make(Native Method)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLContext.<init>(OpenSSLContext.java:152)
    ... 23 more
```

Configuration changes I have tried:

1. Changed `protocol` from HTTP/1.1 to `org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol`
2. Manually set the SSL Implementation to JSSE by `sslImplementationName=org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEImplementation` (Works in some setup and does not in some, irrelevant as we need OpenSSL Implementation)
3. Used APR Connector, `protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"` (Same error)

There is a warning that says `An older version [1.2.23] of the Apache Tomcat Native library is installed, while Tomcat recommends a minimum version of [1.2.38]`, this should not matter in my opinion because TLS 1.3 is supported from version [1.2.18] [Link](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62748)

The only thing left for me to do is debug the source code of Tomcat to step into the org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLContext.(OpenSSLContext.java:152) method. (I don't know how to)

Kindly help me with the configuration problem or guide me how to debug a remote running instance of tomcat (not the webapp inside it)